# How to load child collection after loading the parent with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this model

```
Product
- int Id
- string Name
- List<ProductChannelAffectation> Affectations

ProductChannelAffectation
- Channel Channel
- Product Product
- double Price
```

So I want to get the 10 first product that match to some condition and their affectation in 2 queries (no N+1 problem) and if possible in 1 trip to the DB.

So I read this Answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035649/277067
OR this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285739/277067

But here there is 2 problem :

- The condition is duplicated "Where(x => x.Id == ID)" across the 2 queries, it's ok when it's simple condition but what if it's complicated conditions (involving other tables, text search...)
- There is no "Top" condition.

Lazy loading is here causing a N+1 problem.

I tried this

```
var products = _nhSession.QueryOver<Product>()
    .Where(...)
    .Take(10)
    .List()
    .ToList();
var idsproduct = products.Select(p => p.ID);
var affectation = _nhSession.QueryOver<ProductChannel>()
    .Where(c => c.Product.ID.IsIn(idsproduct))
    .ToList();
```

But there is still N+1 (for getting the affectations) before the second query is executed.

Here is how my association is declared

```
  <bag name="Affectations" access="property" table="Product" lazy="false">
      <key column="n_Product" />
      <one-to-many class="CTV.ProductChannel, CTV" />
    </bag>
```

I'm doing my declaration with activerecord.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a batch size

```
 <bag name="Affectations" ... batch-size='50'>
```

This will stop your n+1 problem and allow you to keep lazy loading. Basically setting batch-size to 50 will reduce the amount of queries issued to the database by a factor of 50. Without it set if you had 99 rows you would issue 99 queries to the database with batch-size set you would issue 2.

Comment: I found it after my question indeed. But it's not behaving as you're saying look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6293687/277067. the documentation is wrong about it.

Comment: What doesn't work? `batch-size` will solve your problem, the question you point at asks "how does batch-size" work. Did you try it and look at the SQL generated?

Comment: Yes I did, for instance, If I have a batch-size of 50, and I have 30 product, it'll first load 25 product's affectations and then 5 product's affectations.

Comment: It's not really a problem in my case, but your explanation is wrong, with a batch size of 50 and 99 product I'll get more than 2 request.

Answer (score 0):

```
// subquery for the ids
var idsproduct = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
    .Where(...)
    .Take(10);
var affectation = _nhSession.QueryOver<Product>()
    .WithSubquery.Where(p => p.ID).In(idsproduct))
    .Fetch(p => p.Affectations).Eager
    .ToList();
```